# Powershell Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true not working correctly

Tags: powershell, security, cmd, windows-defender

I must warn you I don't use powershell much. I am trying to turn off windows defender real time protection via powershell I found the command `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` and tried it in admin privileges only to get this

> Set-MpPreference : Operation failed with the following error:
>   0x800106ba. Operation: Set-MpPreference. Target:
>   DisableRealtimeMonitoring. At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_MpPreference:root\Microsoft...FT_MpPreference)
>   [Set-MpPreference],    CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x800106ba,Set-MpPreference

Any thoughts?

Comment: This works for me but I have to run it manually with a shortcut key, as I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65944287/10802144.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the **Windows Defender antivirus services seem to be *persistently disabled* on your machine**.

It's unfortunate that the `Set-MpPreference` cmdlet reports this in such an obscure fashion.

To fix this problem, ***re-enable* the Windows Defender antivirus services**:

The easiest way to do this is the following, but note that it involves a reboot:

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender' DisableAntiSpyware 0
Restart-Computer
```

- You may instead use the Local Group Policy Editor-based method described in [this windowscentral.com article](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-permanently-disable-windows-defender-windows-10) or use `regedit.exe`'s GUI or us the `reg.exe` CLI utility.
- Note that the linked instructions are slightly outdated - instead of node `Windows Defender`, setting `Turn off Windows Defender`, target node `Windows Defender Antivirus`, setting `Turn off Windows Defender Antivirus`).
- While using the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`) to turn the antivirus services *off* takes effect *immediately*, turning them back *on* *can take minutes* before the services are actually restarted (on the plus side, no reboot is required, unlike what the linked instructions say).
- Note that if you reenable via the registry, such as via the above PowerShell command, while having originally disabled via the [local] group policy, that policy will continue to reflect the disabling in the GUI (however, it is the *registry* setting that matters).

Comment: This is one possible issue, but I'm pretty sure that there can be other issues that cause this, and I still haven't nailed them down.  I see this error randomly on identically spun-up instances on AWS, using AWS-provided AMIs, where my Powershell script is run as part of the launch script.  Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't.  I even added code before this point to check to make sure that the WinDefend service has started running before attempting to disable it, to no avail.  I hope someone eventually comes along with a more complete answer, as this is extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error:

> Add-MpPreference: Operation failed with the following error: 0x%1!x!

check if you're not in an Admin shell. You need to choose Windows PowerShell -> **Run as Administrator**.

Answer (score 0):

Before `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` disable intrusion detection system with the below command:

```
Set-MpPreference -DisableIntrusionPreventionSystem $true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add-MpPreference: The following error occurred during the operation: 0x800106ba. Operation: MpPreference. Destination: ConfigListExtension.

PS: in my work, use Kaspersky

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).