# I can't turn off Real Time Protection via Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-defender, reverse-shell

I want to try reverse shell. I tried to turn off Real Time Protection using Powershell command:
`Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true`

But it doesn't work. I am pretty sure I did everything right. I opened it as administrator and ran the command. I tried restarting the windows, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: @santisq there is nothing

Comment: `(Get-MpPreference).DisableRealtimeMonitoring` still appears as False after running Set?

Comment: @santisq yes. it does

Comment: I don't see any issue with your command, what happens if you try the same from the GUI? Does it get disabled, do you see it as True in PS?

Comment: @santisq yeah. it works that way

Comment: What happens if you stop the service first and then set the attribute? `get-service windefend | Stop-Service -Force`

Comment: I confirmed the same behavior on one of my lab systems. No error, says it's updating when using `verbose`. Can disable in GUI. Even then can't set back to enabled in PS.

Comment: @santisq Stop-Service : Service 'Microsoft Defender Antivirus Service (windefend)' cannot be stopped due to the following error:
 Cannot open windefend service on computer '.'.

Comment: something is definitely wrong with my windows. Can it be because this is education edition of windows?

Comment: Do you have a 3rd party av installed?

Comment: @Doug no. I do not have it

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [Powershell Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960190/powershell-set-mppreference-disablerealtimemonitoring-true-not-working-correct) ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also turn off firewall, too. In PowerShell use this command:

`netsh advfirewall set all profiles state off`

This should do the trick; just tested it with reverse shell in Empire.

Also, keep in mind that uponr reboot, Realtime Monitoring is activated again (if you want persistence, you should find a workaround). Firewall, though, remains deactivated until you enable it again.

Answer (score 0):

I found it guys. I had to turn the tamper protection off. But I found no way to turn it off via powershell on internet